# Switching binary tree subtrees SIGSEV

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I'm trying to switch binary tree subtrees, however I am getting SIGSEV and I don't know how to fix that

My tree struct:

```
typedef struct Tree_node_ Tree_node;
typedef Tree_node* Tree;

struct Tree_node_
{
    int value;
    Tree left;
    Tree right;
};
```

Switching subtrees code:

```
void switch(Tree t) {
    Tree temp = malloc(sizeof(t));
    temp = t;
    t = t->left;
    temp->left = t->right;
    t->right = temp;
}
```

Error is happening when I'm trying to read `t->right`

Comment: `temp = t;` this assignment overwrites the `malloc`.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I've tried allocating new temp, by giving it value, left, right of t, but still no luck.

Comment: `temp` should just be a single pointer: `temp = t->left; t->left = t->right; t->right = temp;` Of course, it already is just a single pointer, but you've confused yourself with the `typedef`. Moral of the story: don't typedef pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> `temp->left = t->right`

**Reason for Segmentation fault** : Here you are assigning `t->left->right` to `temp->left`  because     `t->right = t->left->right` (`t = t->left`).

**Solution** :
`temp = t->left;`
`t->left = t->right;`
`t->right = temp`

There is no need to malloc `temp`. In fact, allocating memory to `temp` cause memory leak, since you are modifying the address stored in `temp` to `t`
(`temp = t`).
I mean, you will lose the pointer to the `malloc`'ed address after the execution of `temp = t` . This will cause memory leak.
Valgrind will give you **definitely lost** error.

Comment: Well I wanted to switch value too, this algorithm doesn't throw an error but it is not what I need

Comment: This is *almost* the right answer, but the last line should be, of course, `t->right = temp;`.

Comment: @printf  Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

```
void switch(Tree t) {
    Tree temp = malloc(sizeof(t));
```

you assign to `temp` pointer a buffer to uninitialized memory allocated with `malloc`.

```
    temp = t;
```

You assign to `temp` the pointer value of `t`.  You leak at this point the memory allocated with `malloc()`, that has no reference pointint to it from this point on.

```
    t = t->left;
```

You change the value of `t` to point to it's left child, but there's no context to know if the left child of `t` does exist or not (probably it is `NULL`)

```
    temp->left = t->right;
```

you now have the two children of the original `t` node pointing to the same `right` child (while original node is still pointed by `temp`)

```
    t->right = temp;
}
```

now `t->right` points to its parent node.

First, there is no need to use `malloc()` as you are supposed to be swithing the children of node `t`, you are not inserting a new node to the tree.  Second, to exchange the values of two variables (be them pointers, numbers or whatever) there's a simple code that allows you to do that, that is:

```
    Type temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
```

so, to switch the children (independently of any of the pointers being null) you have to do:

```
void switch(Tree t) {
    Tree temp = t->left;
    t->left = t->right;
    t->right = temp;
}
```

with no malloc, no more temporary variables, etc.  Even if the children pointers are `NULL` this code works.  If you want also to check for `t` being not null, then:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  /* for EXIT_FAILURE */

void switch(Tree t) {
    if (t == NULL) {
        printf("Illegal parameter NULL passed to switch()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Tree temp = t->left;
    t->left = t->right;
    t->right = temp;
}
```